# Random float number for different scenarios

Tags: python, random, numbers

Is it possible to generate a random float number that is (a,b],(a,b)?
for example, (0,100], it will never be 0, but it can be 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

`random.random()` gives you a floating point number in the range [0.0, 1.0).

For `(a,b]`:

Multiply by 100 and subtract it from 100 to get a random floating number that could be 100 (if the generated random was 0) but will never reach 0 as the generated number cannot be 1.0.

For `(0,100)`:

```
r = 0
while not r:
    r = random.random() * 100
```

etc. You can always reroll if it does not fit your needs.

Comment: +1. Note that proving correctness is a bit subtle, though: the result of `random.random() * 100` is subject to the usual round-ties-to-even rounding, and it's *conceivable* that the result could round up to `100.0` in some cases. It turns out that it doesn't, but on some systems (notably 32-bit Linux, using x87 in 64-bit precision mode for floating-point) and with some multipliers, such as `2049`, that rounding up _is_ a possibilty. (For a related bug report, see https://bugs.python.org/issue24567)

Comment: @Mark wouldn't have imagined. Must really suck to get to experience that bug in production software and even more difficult to get behind why it happened.